# Erro Login Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Não estou conseguindo validar meu login, segue código abaixo:

```
 public ActionResult Login(FormCollection collection)
    {
        AlunoAplicacao bdAluno;
        bdAluno = AlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.AlunoAplicacaoEF();

        var Aluno = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Select(x => x.Email == collection["Email"] && x.Senha == collection["Senha"]);

        if (Aluno.Count() == 1)
        {
            var AlunoOnline = Aluno.First();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(AlunoOnline.ID.ToString(), false);
            return RedirectToAction("AreaAluno");
        }

        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Resposta", new { id = "ErroLogin" });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Qual erro esta aparecendo??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi você está tentando percorrer a lista com essa lambda, portanto a forma correta seria usar o `where`. Além disso, para você conseguir ter uma recepção desse login, você poderia passar o `AlunoOnline.ID` como parametro do seu `RedirectToAction`.

Segue código abaixo:

```
  AlunoAplicacao bdAluno;
        bdAluno = AlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.AlunoAplicacaoEF();

        var Aluno = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Email == collection["Email"] && x.Senha == collection["Senha"]);

        if (Aluno.Count() == 1)
        {
            var AlunoOnline = Aluno.First();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(AlunoOnline.ID.ToString(), false);
            return RedirectToAction("AreaAluno", new { id = AlunoOnline.ID });
        }

        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Resposta", new { id = "ErroLogin" });
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou corretamente.